# Something like DataTable in Android

Tags: android, datatable

I am looking for a way to create a DataTable in Android, a library preferably.

I would need create a table with: Fix headers, row, column, and cell listeners, allow scrolling, sort columns.

If somebody known something like this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try table layout in your xml ?
You can find examples here:

- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/
- http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: The idea would be something like this but in android. https://www.datatables.net/